# start screen UBUNTU 14.04 /mnt/sdc1

Tags: 14.04, mount, disk

i had problems with start screen on UBUNTU 14.04, the message is below ubuntu log before start gnome. > (the disk unity to /mnt/sdc1 is not yeat ready or non mounted or present) and below is writed : Press )S) to scape or (M) to recovery manually!!!!

How can i solve it?

Thanaks a lot and sorry about the bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that Ubuntu cannot find /mnt/sdc1 to mount it. If you have specifically specified "/mnt/sdc1" in your /etc/fstab file, change it to use UUID's instead as the drive has probably changed designations to something else.

For now, press "S" to skip mounting and allow the system to boot, then get into a terminal and type in **blkid** to get the UUID's of each drive on your system.

Identify the drive you originally setup as /mnt/sdc1 and copy down the UUID which will look something like this in the output:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="My_C_Drive" **UUID="7378084A69DC3DF8"** TYPE="ntfs" (A Windows formatted drive)
/dev/sdd1: **UUID="5fc6e3a5-a060-42f6-9368-9fded7e0d048"** TYPE="ext4" (A Linux formatted drive)
```

Then in /etc/fstab, place that UUID down instead of the device name so the line looks something like:

```
**UUID=5fc6e3a5-a060-42f6-9368-9fded7e0d048** /home           ext4    noatime        0       2
```

In the above example, we've setup device /dev/sdd1 which is EXT4 formatted to be mounted as "/home".

Save, reboot and test.

Comment: Thank you for answer me, right, i see the line written for i dont know KKK :) thanks a lot brow!!!!